# `tf.estimator.RunConfig` vs `tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig`

Tags: tensorflow

I am confused regarding whether I should be using `tf.estimator.RunConfig` or `tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig` to pass a `RunConfig` to an estimator.

using `tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig` is straightforward:

```
rc = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=1,
                                model_dir=model_dir)
```

But `tf.estimator.RunConfig` has some odd syntax:

```
rc = tf.estimator.RunConfig()
rc = rc.replace(save_checkpoints_secs=1,
                model_dir=model_dir)
```

Is there any reason to prefer one `RunConfig` over the other? The documentation is not clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please prefer core version, i.e. `tf.estimator.RunConfig`. 
`tf.contrib.learn.*` will be deprecated soon.
BTW, you can do `tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_check...)`